# navigator.vibrate not working in mobile devices even?

Tags: javascript

I want to vibrate mobile device which supports vibration. using this nothing happens in three mobile devices I tested:

```js
const vibrate = document.getElementById('vibrate')

vibrate.addEventListener('click', event => {
  navigator.vibrate(200);
});
```

```html
<button id="vibrate">vibrate</button>
```

What's wrong here? how can I fix this?

Comment: On what phone you try to run this example and what browser version?

Comment: redmi note 10, moto e10, samsung note 4

Comment: Are you using a browser (Chrome?) or something like a react native app?

Comment: I used last android chrome. can you confirm this is working in your device?

Comment: yes, it works on my android phone.

Comment: You can't do anything with it. It's because of the `user activation`. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation

Comment: it's inside addEventListener so user activation is ok !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's different on some devices. For the events that have `isTrusted` set to true, you can use Navigator Vibration. In some devices, `click` event is not trusted so we can use an alternate event which is `pointerDown`. I tested out this event on *redmi note 10* and worked correctly.
 
 Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation)
**Note that** it might still don't work on some devices.

```js
const vibrate = document.getElementById('vibrate')

vibrate.addEventListener('pointerdown', event => {
  navigator.vibrate(200);
});
```

```html
<button id="vibrate">vibrate</button>
```